# jQuery: Change selection of 2nd dropdown based on selection of 1st

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdownbox

I have two drop down lists and I would like to make it when someone selects value 2 from dropdown1, dropdown2 is automatically changed to value 4.

```
<select id="dropdwon1">
<option value="1">Item1</option>
<option value="2">Item2</option>
<option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdwon2">
<option value="3">Item1</option>
<option value="4">Item2</option>
<option value="5">Item3</option>
</select>
```

I have seen how this can be done when the values are the same but not when they are different. Looking for a simple solution like this below.

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
$("#dropdwon2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will need to have some sort of mapping, either coded or pulled from a database, to know that "When dropdown1 is 2, dropdown2 should be set to 4".

Comment: @ThiefMaster, s/s\/dropdwon\/dropdown/s\/dropdwon\/dropdown\//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing it seems like you want to have the `selectedIndex` in sync.

Here's how:

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zyTck/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#dropdwon1").change(function() {
        $("#dropdwon2")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Yes, this works will for what I am doing. Thanks Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
   $("#dropdwon2").val( +this.value + 2 );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PWzav/4/)**

`+this.value` will converted into number so you can add `2`.

**OR**

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
   $("#dropdwon2").prop('selectedIndex', this.selectedIndex );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PWzav/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function(){
   var ind = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
   $('#dropdown2 option').eq(ind).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ac1=$("#dd1").val();
$("#dd2").val(ac1);
```