# How to select 2nd value from dropdown from 1st dropdown selection with JQuery in Zend Form

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, select, dropdownbox

In my Zend Form I have 2 select boxes, each selecting a different column in the same table.
How can I make these two items dependent: if a value in box1 is selected the matching value in box2 is selected and if I select a value in box2 the matching value in box1 is selected.
This way I can choose to select on either column.

My Table:

id code description

1     A      Apples

2     B      Bananas

My Form elements:

```
$objcode = new Zend_Form_Element_Select( 'code'); 
$objcode 
->setRequired(false)
->setAttrib('id','code');
->...more attributes to cleanup input
$this->addElement($objcode );

$objdescription = new Zend_Form_Element_Select( 'description'); 
$objdescription
->setRequired(true)
->setAttrib('id','description');
->...more attributes to cleanup input
$this->addElement($objdescription);
```

View:

```
<td>Box1</td>
<td><?php echo $this->objForm->code?></td>
<td>Box2</td>
<td><?php echo $this->objForm->description?></td>
```

So if I select B in box1, the selected value in box2 should change to Bananas. If I then select Apples in box2 the value in box1 should change to A.

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889030/jquery-change-selection-of-2nd-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-1st) using jQuery but didn't succeed and this is only one way (box 2 is dependent on box 1 but box1 is not dependent on box 2). 
I am sure I need JQuery on change event to handle this but I am not sure if to put jQuery in the Form or in the View and how?

I tried adding this attribute in Form element Code:

```
->setAttrib('onChange','javascript: OnChangeCode();')
```

And adding in View:

```
function OnChangeCode()
    {
    JQuery("#code").change(function () {
        JQuery("#description")[0].selectedIndex = JQuery(this)[0].selectedIndex;
        });
    }
```

With no result however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function OnChangeCode()
{
    jQuery("#description")[0].selectedIndex = jQuery("#code")[0].selectedIndex;
}
```

note : I think it's `jQuery` instead of `JQuery`

Another way to do like the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889030/jquery-change-selection-of-2nd-dropdown-based-on-selection-of-1st):

1 - remove `->setAttrib('onChange','javascript: OnChangeCode();')`

2 replace your function by :

```
$(function() {
    $("#code").change(function() {
        $("#description")[0].selectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Both, the second way is easier so I will go for that one.

Comment: Happy for you. :) Good Luck.